# Why does double free error occurs in linked lists?

Tags: c, runtime-error, free

I'm trying to write a function which deletes some certain nodes from a linked lists. These nodes represent circles. I'm getting "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" error in free(toDelete); line. Any ideas why this happens?
Edit: I changed toDelete and replaced it with tempPtr. Error disappeared. It worked properly on first try. Now it works with the list wrong. No error tho.

```
BaseCircPtr DeleteCirc()
{
    int control = 0;
    BaseCircPtr sPtr = CircList;
    BaseCircPtr tempPtr = sPtr;
    BaseCircPtr tempSPtr = sPtr;
    BaseCircPtr nextPtr = tempPtr->next;
    BaseCircPtr prevPtr = NULL;
    BaseCircPtr toDelete = NULL;
    float DstCir = 0;
    while(nextPtr != NULL)
    {
        prevPtr = tempPtr;
        DstCir = Distance(tempPtr->CX, nextPtr->CX, tempPtr->CY, nextPtr->CY);
        if(DstCir < (tempPtr->CR + nextPtr->CR))
           {
            if(tempPtr->CR > nextPtr->CR){
                    tempPtr->next = nextPtr->next;
                    free(nextPtr);
                    tempPtr = tempPtr->next;
                    nextPtr = tempPtr->next;
                    control = 1;}

                else{
                    toDelete = tempPtr;
                        if(toDelete = sPtr)
                            {
                                sPtr = sPtr->next;
                                tempPtr = tempPtr->next;
                                free(toDelete);
                                control = 1;
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            prevPtr->next = tempPtr->next;
                            free(tempPtr);
                            tempPtr = prevPtr->next;
                            control = 1;
                        }
                    }

    }
    if(DstCir > (tempPtr->CR + nextPtr->CR))
    {
        nextPtr = nextPtr->next;
        tempPtr = tempPtr->next;
        if(control = true)
            prevPtr = prevPtr->next;
        control = 1;
    }

    if(control = true)
        prevPtr = prevPtr->next;

        if(nextPtr == NULL && tempSPtr->next != NULL)
        {
            tempPtr = tempSPtr;
            nextPtr = tempPtr->next;
            tempSPtr = tempSPtr->next;
            control = 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `{}` around the function body. Please repost the actual code. And indent it correctly.

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger?  If you're dealing with a circular list, then you're probably not  properly handling the case when you reach the first pointer again.

Comment: @Barmar I know. It just bugs out when I put it in the text here. It's my first post here :( sorry

Comment: `if(toDelete = sPtr)` looks suspicious.  Likewise `if(control = true)`.  Your compiler should be emitting warnings about unintentional assignment.

Comment: @Den-Jason oh gawd. I make this mistake all the time. You're right. It didn't fix it, but it's worth noticing still